# Utilizando Case ou if

Tags: sql, select, if, case, when

Sou iniciante em SQL e estou tendo dificuldade em utilizar o `CASE WHEN`.

Tenho uma tabela chamada `CRM_PROCESSO`, na qual tem uma coluna com a opção de `Status`, o porém é que a resposta deste status é numérico, sendo `1 - Aberto` , `2 - Cancelado`, `3- Encerrado` e `4 - Parcial`.

Do modo que criei o comando abaixo, ele está trazendo exatamente o número do status.

Qual comando utilizaria, para que esse número alterasse para a resposta informada acima, uma vez que já usei um `CASE`?

```
select cp.idprocesso,
    cpv.descricao,
    cpv.valoratual,
    cp.status,
    CASE cpv.descricao
    when '/*CENTRODECUSTO*/' THEN 'Local de Negócio'
    When '/*NUMERONOTA*/' Then 'Número da Nota'
    wHEN '/*Datasolicitao*/' THEN 'Data da Solicitação' 
    wHEN '/*Dataemissao*/' THEN 'Data de Emissão da NF' 
    wHEN '/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/' THEN 'Motivo do Cancelamento' 
    When '/*SOLICITANTE*/' THEN 'Solicitante'
    end as descricaovariavel, 1 as QNDT
   FROM CRM_PROCESSO CP,
        CRM_PROCESSO_VARIAVEL CPV
        WHERE
        (CP.IDPROCESSO = CPV.IDPROCESSO) 
        AND ( CP.IDPROCEDIMENTO = 34)
        AND (CP.STATUS = 0/*STATUS*/)

   AND ( CPV.DESCRICAO IN ('/*CENTRODECUSTO*/','/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/','/*NUMERONOTA*/','/*datasolicitao','/*dataemissao*/','/*solicitante*/') )
```

Por favor me ajudem!

Comment: Renan bem vindo. Não seria melhor criar uma table "TIPO_STATUS" com esse valores e simplesmente fazer um `join`? Não precisaria de um monte de case, e nem alterar o select caso precise incluir/excluir valores de status, basta fazer as alterações na tabela "TIPO_STATUS"

Comment: Eu ia responder mas parece que você está desenrolando. A ideia dada por @RicardoPontual pra mim é a ideal, mas caso queira uma alternativa, usa o `case` (como faz na outra coluna)

Comment: agora voltando à sua pergunta, não entendi bem o que você que fazer, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: @RicardoPontual... tentarei explicar do modo leigo meu... 
Tenho duas tabelas prontas do sistema, não consigo editar elas.  Em uma chamada "crm_processo'' existe diversas informações, desta preciso apenas da informação : IDPROCESSO e IDSTATUS.

Comment: A questão é que quando ele consulta essa tabela, o campo status trás o número, e preciso de um comando que ele altere o número para descrição.
Consegui explicar melhor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar quantos `CASE` quiser em seu Script, pode não ficar muito prático, mas pode...
Pelo que entendi seria isso que você quer:

```
SELECT cp.idprocesso
      ,cpv.descricao
      ,cpv.valoratual
      ,(CASE cp.status
          WHEN 1 THEN 'Aberto'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'Cancelado'
          WHEN 3 THEN 'Encerrado'
          WHEN 4 THEN 'Parcial'
        END)                                                          AS status
      ,(CASE cpv.descricao
          WHEN '/*CENTRODECUSTO*/'      THEN 'Local de Negócio'
          WHEN '/*NUMERONOTA*/'         THEN 'Número da Nota'
          WHEN '/*Datasolicitao*/'      THEN 'Data da Solicitação' 
          WHEN '/*Dataemissao*/'        THEN 'Data de Emissão da NF' 
          WHEN '/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/' THEN 'Motivo do Cancelamento' 
          WHEN '/*SOLICITANTE*/'        THEN 'Solicitante'
        END)                                                          AS descricaovariavel
      ,1                                                              AS QNDT
  FROM      CRM_PROCESSO          CP
 INNER JOIN CRM_PROCESSO_VARIAVEL CPV ON CPV.IDPROCESSO = CP.IDPROCESSO
 WHERE (CP.IDPROCEDIMENTO = 34)
   AND (CP.STATUS         = 0)/*STATUS*/
   AND (CPV.DESCRICAO     IN ('/*CENTRODECUSTO*/','/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/','/*NUMERONOTA*/','/*datasolicitao','/*dataemissao*/','/*solicitante*/'))
```

Você pode também seguir a dica que foi dada pelo @RicardoPontual em sua pergunta e criar uma tabela `TIPO_STATUS` com os campos `ID` e `DESCRICAO`

Comment: Deu certo Matheus deste modo, que mandou.
Talvez por ser mega iniciantes esse passo já me atende perfeitamente. oBRIGADO PELA AJUDA!!

Comment: Maravilha, com o tempo você vai entendendo melhor e aperfeiçoando seus métodos!